# How to group weekly data in it respective months and plot using Apache Echarts

Tags: echarts

I have the weekly avg from last 5 years, last year, and the year to date.

I would like to show them in a line graph, but showing the respective months in the xaxis...

for example and based on this year:

January has 4 weeks, so xaxis shows jan and there are 4 marks in the chart representing weeks 1,2,3 and 4;

February also has 4 weeks, so xaxis shows feb and there are 3 marks in the chart representing week 5,6,7 and 8;
and so on;

i'm using:

```
VueJs: 2.6.10
Echarts: 4.9.0
```

here is my code:

```js
// var motnhNames = [
//   'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
//   'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
// ]
var monthNames = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38,
  39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52
]

var options = {
  title: {
    text: 'My data'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['5 Years', 'Last Year', 'YTD']
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
      dataZoom: {
        yAxisIndex: 'none'
      },
      dataView: {
        readOnly: false
      },
      magicType: {
        type: ['line', 'bar']
      },
      restore: {},
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: monthNames
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
  },
  series: [{
      name: '5 Years',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        19, 46, 34, 33, 16, 3, 6, 33, 20,
        25, 5, 29, 48, 36, 1, 28, 48, 1,
        34, 22, 50, 38, 11, 11, 37, 11, 28,
        15, 14, 5, 7, 2, 46, 3, 12, 10,
        20, 50, 39, 17, 50, 7, 27, 6, 5,
        11, 35, 25, 50, 18, 40, 30, 35
      ],
      lineStyle: {
        type: 'dashed',
        width: 5
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Last Year',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        17, 48, 30, 6, 29, 27, 8, 50, 28,
        34, 38, 48, 28, 41, 24, 27, 15, 17,
        13, 50, 9, 15, 18, 41, 43, 49, 19,
        1, 22, 20, 27, 1, 18, 26, 48, 17,
        25, 38, 1, 29, 28, 1, 42, 21, 7,
        8, 6, 6, 47, 50, 6, 46, 41
      ],
      lineStyle: {
        type: 'dotted',
        width: 5
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'YTD',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        17, 48, 30, 6, 29, 27, 8, 50, 28,
        34, 38, 48, 28, 41, 24, 27, 15, 17,
        13, 50, 9, 15, 18, 41, 43, 49, 19,
        1, 22, 20, 27, 1, 18, 26, 48, 17,
        25, 38, 1, 29, 28, 1, 42, 21, 7,
        8, 6, 6, 47, 50, 6, 46
      ],
      lineStyle: {
        type: 'solid',
        width: 5
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved adding a new xaxis layer and hide the first one...

```js
xAxis: [
  {
    type: "category",
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: this.generateData(false, 51),
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: (param) => {
        return this.getMonthFromWeek(param, 2021);
      }
    },
    show: false
  },
  {
    position: "bottom",
    type: "category",
    data: [
      "Jan",
      "Fev",
      "Mar",
      "Abr",
      "Mai",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Ago",
      "Set",
      "Out",
      "Nov",
      "Dez"
    ],
    xAxisIndex: 2
  }
],
```

here is sandbox code [result](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-danny-mnjbp?file=/index.html:2159-2167)!

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE 1]**

I added a function that translate the week number to the respective month:

```js
getDateOfWeek(week: number, year: number): string {
  let date = (1 + (week - 1) * 7);
  let dateOfYear = new Date(year, 0, date)
  let month = dateOfYear.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { month: 'short' });
  month = month.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + month.slice(1).replace('.', '')
  return month;
}
```

also added a `axisLabel`:

```js
options: {
 ...,
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: (param: number) => {
      return this.getDateOfWeek(param, 2021)
    },
  },
  ...,
}
```

Now i have the month name on xaxis as expected... Only need to suppress duplicated names or maybe define a limit for 12 ticks.

I've tried to use `xaxis.splitNumber` property, but as the [docs says](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.splitNumber), it is not allowed for `category` axis...

I was wondering, if i could change the week number to a date object, like:

```js
firstWeek = '2021-01-01'
secondWeek = '2021-01-08'
```

should i change it to time series and work with real dates on X Axis?
not sure if it would solve the problem or bring another :|

here is the result so far:
[image: chart]